# How to use LIKE operator basing on Boolean datatype in SQL queries?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to match a string value with a Boolean value using Like operator like this:

```
String param = 'True';
sqlQuery = 'SELECT CompanyName FROM User WHERE OR IsActive LIKE :param';
```

Since it's not working and doesn't fetch any data from the table, I also tried this query:

```
 String param= Active;
 Boolean activeCheck=true ;

    if(param=='Active'){
        activeCheck=true;
    }
    else if(param=='Down'){
        activeCheck=false;
    }
  sqlQuery = sqlQuery = 'SELECT CompanyName FROM User WHERE IsActive LIKE :activeCheck';
```

Still no luck.

Comment: please tack with db platform

Comment: `LIKE` is for string (character) matching. It does not work on other data types such as boolean, integer or numeric data. In your specific case, it appears that you're looking for `WHERE (ColA = :param) or (ColB = :param)` instead.

Comment: Also, any basic SQL tutorial will show you that `WHERE OR` is totally invalid syntax, regardless of the DBMS you're using.

Comment: @kenWhite, thanks for your response. That OR was typo. I've fixed this.

Comment: If you copy/paste your actual code, you can't have a typo. :-) You should use your real code, not something you made up or retyped for your question. The error is still in your post, however. Your second code example should be `WHERE IsActive = :activeCheck`.

Comment: In case it's not clear from my previous comments, `LIKE` is used to test similarity, not equality. It's also intended to be used on character data and with a wildcard, such as `WHERE LastName LIKE `Sm%'`, which would match "Smith" and "Smyth" and *Smithers". For other types of data, you use other operators, such as `= > < >= <=` or `BETWEEN`.

Comment: I made it work. Thanks @KenWhite. The logic was to use = operator and decalare if else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be by modifying your query with some sub-queries might actually work.

You could follow the below approach if that's fine for you. It worked for me.

```
SELECT COMPANYNAME FROM 
(
SELECT COMPANYNAME, 
CASE WHEN ISACTIVE=1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' 
END AS ACTIVECHECK
FROM
Users) B
WHERE B.ACTIVECHECK LIKE:param
```

Comment: For what it appears that the poster is trying to do, this is a horrific solution. There's no reason for three separate SELECT statements to compare columns for equality to a value when a simple OR works much better. Try viewing the execution plan for a simple OR as opposed to what you've written here.

Comment: The three select statement was a mistake. Now its just a single sub-query. If you feel like mine is not good, then give a nice approach if you could.

Comment: @KenWhite: there is only one real SELECT statement in that query. The derived table (`B`) is only syntactic sugar to be able to use the column alias in the WHERE clause. And the comparison of a CASE expression is typically not that much worse than an OR (both are hard to optimize)